# Remove duplicated tuples with included lists from list

Tags: python, set, tuples

i have a list with tuples:

```
managed_list = [ ('a', [1,2]), ('a', [1,2]), ('b', [2,2]), ('b', [2,2])]
```

need to get:

```
managed_list = [ ('a', [1,2]), ('b', [2,2]) ]
```

tried:

```
seen = set()
[[n for n in x if n not in seen and not seen.add(n)] for x in managed_list]
```

getting:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 3):

Right, you can't use a `list` or a structure containing a `list` (or another unhashable type) in a `set`. Without changing your input structure, you could use `itertools.groupby` and then just discard the iterator through the duplicates:

```
import itertools
uniques = [x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(sorted(managed_list))]
```

Incidentally if it were not for the unhashable key issue (e.g. if the lists were tuples instead), your expression could be simplified to:

```
list(set(managed_list))
```

You do not need the extra code in the list comprehension for this.

Comment: Good thing to note is that `itertools.groupby` requires the input to be sorted to work globally, otherwise it'll work on contiguous elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `collections.OrderedDict` to remove duplicate keys.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict([ ('a', [1,2]), ('a', [1,2]), ('b', [2,2]), ('b', [2,2])]).items()
[ ('a', [1,2]), ('b', [2,2]) ]
```

Keep in mind that in case of duplicate keys, the right-most entry will be the one included in the output.